# grails version release dates

Tags: grails

In general, I'm trying to find the different the dates of past version releases, but particularly version 1.3.7.

I'm dealing with something that still isn't working in 1.3.7 but should be fixed in 1.3.7?, i.e. these issues: [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7052) and [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7062)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Releases are announced on the mailing list, so they're archived at the Nabble forums. Go to http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-user-f1312389.html and search for "1.3.7 release", "1.3.6 release", etc. and the announcement email will be in the results.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_(framework)) it was released on Feb 27 2011.

Comment: :-), I guess they have it there in the corner of the page, but no write-up / listing of the different versions, i.e. 1.3.6.  Usually wikipedia articles list that?